# log messages to an array/list with logging

Tags: python, logging

Currently am using python logging to log messages to a log file and to console (if --verbose).

How can I configure logging to also record messages into an array/list?

Comment: Been working on this for many hours, after posting this question I just figured it out after 30 minutes or so

Answer (score 10):

1. Figured this out after posting.
2. Used a Stream to a string.
3. Here is snippet of the code, not including the stdout Stream and the normal logger file handle:

   ```
   import io
   import logging

   logger = logging.getLogger()
   errors = io.StringIO()
   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(module)s.%(funcName)s() - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   eh = logging.StreamHandler(errors)
   eh.setFormatter(formatter)
   logger.addHandler(eh)

   logger.error("This is a test error message")
   contents=errors.getvalue()
   print("error string=>{}".format(contents))
   errors.close()
   ```

Comment: I get 'TypeError: can't write str to text stream' with python 2.6.