# Python logging failes with log-file on network drive (windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, logging, network-drive

I want to log using python's logging module to a file on a network drive. My problem is that the logging fails at some random point giving me this error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programme\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1085, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "c:\programme\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1065, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Call stack:
  File "log_test.py", line 67, in <module>
    logger_root.error('FLUSH!!!'+str(i))
Message: 'Minute:120'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programme\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1085, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "c:\programme\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1065, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Call stack:
  File "log_test.py", line 67, in <module>
    logger_root.error('FLUSH!!!'+str(i))
Message: 'FLUSH!!!120'
Arguments: ()
```

I am on a virtual machine with Windows 10 (Version 1909) and I am using Python 3.8.3 and logging 0.5.1.2. The script runs in an virtual environment on a network drive, where the log files are stored.
I am writing a script that is automating some data quality control tasks and I am not 100% sure, where (network drive, local drive, etc.) the script will end up on, so it should be able to log in every possible situation. The error does not appear at the same position/line in the script but randomly. Sometimes the program (~120 minutes in total) finishes without the error appearing at all.

**What I tried so far:**

I believe that the logfile is closed at some point so that no new logging messages can be written to it. I wrote a simple script that basically only does logs to check if it is related to my original script or the logging process itself. Since the "only-logs-script" also fails randomly, when running on the network drive but not when it is running on my local drive, I assume that it is related to the connection to the network drive. I thought about having the whole logging stored in the memory and then written to the file but the MemoryHandler will also open the file at the beginning of the script and therefore fail at some point.

Here is my code for the "only-logs-script" (`log_test.py`):

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import datetime
import time

##################################################################
# setting up a logger to create a log file with information about this programm
logfile_dir = 'logfiles_test'
CHECK_FOLDER = os.path.isdir(logfile_dir)

# if folder doesn't exist, create it
if not CHECK_FOLDER:
    os.makedirs(logfile_dir)
    print("created folder : ", logfile_dir)
log_path = '.\\'+logfile_dir+'\\'
Current_Date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime ('%Y-%m-%d_')
log_filename = log_path+Current_Date+'logtest.log'

print(log_filename)

# Create a root logger
logger_root = logging.getLogger()

# Create handlers
f1_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, mode='w+')
f2_handler = logging.StreamHandler() 

f1_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f2_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create formatters and add it to handlers
f1_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s \n')
f2_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s \n')

f1_handler.setFormatter(f1_format)
f2_handler.setFormatter(f2_format)

# create a memory handler
memoryhandler = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(
                    capacity=1024*100,
                    flushLevel=logging.ERROR,
                    target=f1_handler,
                    flushOnClose=True
                    )


# Add handlers to the logger
logger_root.addHandler(memoryhandler)
logger_root.addHandler(f2_handler)

logger_root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger_root.info('Log-File initiated.')

fname = log_path+'test.log'
open(fname, mode='w+')

for i in range(60*4):
    print(i)
    logger_root.warning('Minute:'+str(i))
    print('Write access:', os.access(fname, os.W_OK))
    if(i%10==0):
        logger_root.error('FLUSH!!!'+str(i))
    time.sleep(60)
```

Is there something horribly wrong with my logging process or is it because of the network drive? And does anyone of you have any ideas on how to tackle this issue? Would storing the whole information in the memory and writing it to a file in the end solve the problem? How would I best achieve this?
Another idea would be to log on the local drive and then automatically copy the file to the network drive, when the script is done. Any help is strongly appreciated as I have tried to identify and solve this problem for several days now.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like some kind of problem with the full path to the file. Try to use only one type of slash ('\\') in path. Try to just test file write access with `open` to a txt file on a network drive in loop.

Comment: I tried several different types of slash combinations like all ('\\') and all ('/') and it did not change anything. The write access seems to be True all the time :( I added the changes to the question. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: well I tested your script and it worked without errors (Win7 x64, Python 3.8 x32). I guess your problem is unrelated to logging module. You said that you are using some VM. In my expirience virtual folders in VirtualBox is not as reliable as a _real_ shared folders so if you are using vbox then try to update it or update Guest Additions.

Comment: Thank you @viilpe for testing my script and for the suggestions, I will see what I can do!

Comment: Is it possible that the script is being run accidentally twice (two independent instances) at or near the same time putting a lock on the log file?

Alternative suggestion to your problem would be to run your script on your VM as you are doing and have the host machine running a logging server that takes logs in passed over the network.

Another alternative is to log locally to the VM then once the process is complete you run a post process to merge/move/overwrite logs from VM to the network share.  If you need to concat logs maybe Pandas can help with that to nuke dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not really going anywhere atm I will post what I did to "solve" my problem. It is not a satisfactory solution as it fails when the code fails but it is better than not logging at all.
The solution is inspired by the answer to this question: [log messages to an array/list with logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364346/log-messages-to-an-array-list-with-logging)

So here is what I did:

```
import io

#####################################
# first create an in-memory file-like object to save the logs to
log_messages = io.StringIO()

# create a stream handler that saves the log messages to that object
s1_handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_messages)
s1_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler just in case
f1_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, mode='w+')
f1_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# set the format for the log messages
log_format = '%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s \n'
f1_format = logging.Formatter(log_format)
s1_handler.setFormatter(f1_format)
f1_format = logging.Formatter(log_format)

# add the handler to the logger
logger_root.addHandler(s1_handler)
logger_root.addHandler(f1_handler)

#####################################
# here would be the main code ...

#####################################
# at the end of my code I added this to write the in-memory-message to the file
contents = log_messages.getvalue()
# opening a file in 'w'
file = open(log_filename, 'w')
# write log message to file
file.write("{}\n".format(contents))
# closing the file and the in-memory object
file.close()
log_messages.close()
```

Obviously this fails when the code fails but the code tries to catch most errors, so I hope it will work. I got rid of the Memory handler but kept a file handler so that in case of a real failure at least some of the logs are recorded until the file handler fails. It is far from ideal but it works for me atm. If you have some other suggestions/improvements I would be happy to hear them!